# prove $V = Span(S)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $S= \{v_1,\dots,v_p\} \subset \mathbb F^n$ and $V$ be the subspace $\operatorname{span}(S)$. Suppose $v$ is in $S$. Then prove that $V = \operatorname{span}(S \setminus \{v\})$ if and only if $v$ can be written as a linear combination of some vectors in $S \setminus \{v\}$.

So, I felt that the phrasing of the question was confusing, but I tried proving the backwards statement first. Given that $v$ can be written as a linear combination of some of the vectors, then the set $S$ is linearly dependent, by definition. By using this property, we can say that the set $S$ is linearly dependent. After that, how would I relate it to $V$, and how would I prove the forwards statement as well?

Comment: Perhaps try via contradiction. To get you started, suppose $v$ can not be written as a linear combination of the vectors in $S\backslash \{v\}$. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Suppose $\vec{v}$ is a linear combination of some of the vectors in $S\setminus\{\vec{v}\}$ then a basis $B$ for $S$ does not contain $\vec{v}$ and $V=\text{span}(S)=\text{span}(B)=\text{span}(S\setminus \{\vec{v}\})$ where $B \subseteq S\setminus \{\vec{v}\}\subseteq S$.

If $\text{span}(S)=\text{span}(S\setminus \{\vec{v}\})$ then because $\vec{v} \in S$, $\vec{v} \in \text{span}(S)=\text{span}(S\setminus \{\vec{v}\})$ and because $\text{span}(S\setminus \{\vec{v}\})$ is the set of all linear combinations of the vector in $S\setminus \{\vec{v}\}$, $\vec{v}$ must be a linear combination of the vectors in $S\setminus \{\vec{v}\}$.

Hope this helps~!